# Extending class from external 3rd party typescript module

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord, discord.js, typescript-typings

Hello I have a problem with overwriting types

I want overwrite a type from a libary that adds a property to an other library's typings, the line is: https://github.com/discord-akairo/discord-akairo/blob/e092ce4e0c9e749418601476bcd054a30a262785/src/index.d.ts#L14

and in my code I declare it like this:

```
declare module 'discord.js' {
    export interface Message {
        util?: KopekUtil;
    }
}
```

KopekUtil is extending the CommandUtil and the error i get is:

```
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type. Property 'util' must be of type 'CommandUtil', but here has type 'KopekUtil'.  index.d.ts(16, 13): 'util' was also declared here.
```

Comment: Did you try to extend your KopekUtil class, so that it implements CommandUtil? e.g. interface KopekUtil extends CommandUtil{
   //extension methods or properties
}. In case of doubt please post your KopekUtil class so I can reason about your intentions

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ShockTr/5bdc131dec04dd8a3984946d6a978736 this is my KopekUtil class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned trying to extend Command util class like so

```
export class KopekUtil extends CommandUtil{
    constructor(handler, message: Message | CommandInteraction) {
        super(handler, <Message>message);
    }

    send(options:string | MessageOptions , reply? : boolean){
       //your logic
    }
}
```

But I'm afraid it's not possible to overwrite a class that comes from external typescript module.
Although you can introduce a new method in class from external module or extend one of existing methods using object protoype.

**The right way to do that**

util.js

```
declare module 'discord-akairo'{
  export interface CommandUtil {
    mySendMethod(options:string | MessageOptions , reply?:any) : boolean
  } 
};

CommandUtil.prototype.mySendMethod = function (options:string | MessageOptions , reply?:any) : boolean{
  return true;
}
```

Typescript now merges interfaces and you can use your extension

```
const message = new Message(new Client(),{},new TextChannel(new Guild(new Client(),{})))
message.util.mySendMethod("hello")
```

Comment: Thanks! and i have a question if i change the prototype it only changes it on that variable right

Comment: If by that you mean, that only CommandUtil class from discord-akairo will have access to the code you've written, then you're right! Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes to understand prototypes better